# TDS: What to do with the imperial flag icon?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Today I got an red icon with a white imperial flag in the bottom left corner. I thought it was a deco droid so I clicked on it. The up/down lever appeared. I stopped in each of my levels but nothing happened. What now? I can't access the other icons such as the yellow finished one or the rebel spies one.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you updated to the newest version of the game. 1.4.3 (IOS), I had a similar issue until I updated the game.